# Turned Dynamic Web project into Maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat7

I turned my Dynamic Web project into a Maven project in eclipse.There are errors in my pom file and I can't do a maven clean. What do I need to do?

Below is some information that I hope will help you knowing what's wrong:

When doing a Maven clean i get a BUILD FAILED with feedback:

```
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out -> [Help 1]
```

My pom file has two errors:

The first error is on the line:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
```

The first error message is:

Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - connect timed out
    - No plugin found for prefix 'war' in the current project and in the plugin groups [] available

The second error is on the line:

```
<plugins>
```

The second error message is:
CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.1: ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out

Answer (score 0):

Try using this : Right click on project then in **Maven** then click on **Update Project...**. Then update project by checking **Force Update of Snapshots/Releases**.